# Tycho Maven: Export Product with third party bundles and features

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Currently I have a RCP project and I want to export product using [Tycho-packaging](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/product-export-mojo.html), but I have third party plugins and features, any idea that how can I manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But what is your problem? If you have added those 3rd party plugins to the target platform - they will be exported by Tycho. If you have those as projects in your workspace - add pom.xml to each of such project with appropriate packaging type: `"eclipse-plugin"`, `"eclipse-feature"`, etc. If these projects are shared between server and client, and require different packaging types, configure parent pom.xml of your client projects with something, like this

```
<module>../commons/pom.osgi.xml</module>
```

where pom.osgi.xml contains packaging type for Tycho and "commons" project contains standard pom.xml with server packaging type (for example "jar").

UPD: Example contents of pom.osgi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>5.4.0.v20140625-0169</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>app.client</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent.project.path</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>com.company.activity</artifactId>
</project>
```

Contents of MANIFEST.MF

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.company.activity
```

Also, versions in both pom.osgi.xml and MANIFEST.MF must match - that is why our build system is configured to update both of these files.

UPD 2:
Target Platform pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <product.dir>${project.basedir}/eclipse</product.dir>
        <p2.dir>${project.basedir}/../repository/base</p2.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Eclipse Helios -->
        <!-- Includes JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>rcp-helios</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipse.rcp.version}</version>
            <type>zip</type>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Delta Pack for MultiPlatform Build -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-pack</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipse.rcp.version}</version>
            <classifier>pack</classifier>
            <type>zip</type>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- babel.de Language Pack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>BabelLanguagePack-de</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipse.babel.version}</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${product.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../ajdt/eclipse</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-eclipseRcp</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.eclipse</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>rcp-helios,delta-pack,BabelLanguagePack-de</includeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${product.dir}/../</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>rcp-helios,delta-pack,BabelLanguagePack-de</excludeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${product.dir}/plugins</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <artifactItems>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${product.dir}/plugins</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                    ....
                                    <!-- Jersey -->
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}</version>
                                    <destFileName>org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client_${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}</version>
                                    <destFileName>org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client-source_${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                                <!-- SLF4j -->
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                                    <destFileName>slf4j.api_${slf4j.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                                    <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
                                     <destFileName>ch.qos.logback.core_${ch.qos.logback.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                                 ....
                                 <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                                    <destFileName>jackson-mapper-asl_${jackson-mapper-asl.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                    <version>${jackson-mapper-asl.version}</version>
                                </dependency>

                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                                    <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
                                    <destFileName>org.hamcrest.all_${hamcrest.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                </dependency>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>publish-features-and-bundles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <metadataRepositoryLocation>${p2.dir}</metadataRepositoryLocation>
                    <artifactRepositoryLocation>${p2.dir}</artifactRepositoryLocation>
                    <sourceLocation>${product.dir}</sourceLocation>
                    <publishArtifacts>true</publishArtifacts>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>eclipse</directory>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${p2.dir}</directory>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Hello Alexander! Many thanks for your pront answer. I have thought on the possibility of change the type of packaging and configure as profile on the parent pom and I could active before to use export-product. The problem is that one of the tycho requiments is that the artifactId it has to be the same as the Bundle-SymbolicName that is included on the MANIFEST.MF. And I has configure with another name, that is why I'm looking for other options. I will try to define on my target platform. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Alexander! I have tried to create a directory with the plugins that I need,  but the problem is that Tycho-Target platform not supports the type of directory. I have tried to include as a dependency and configure the tycho-platform considering the pomDependencies, but still doesn't works. Any idea that how can I manage it?

Comment: In our project we build target platform by maven. So, it downloads everything from repositories, either public or our private. Please see example pom.xml of our Target platform project.

Comment: @CristinaGalán, I am glad I could help. You may want to accept an answer as correct one, so that it would be easier for others to understand.